# FLEX - Load anglularJS URL content

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript

I need to load a URL (below) in my panel Flex but angularjs is not loading.

What is the solution?

```
<s:Panel id="panelHtml" x="0" y="22" width="100%" height="95%" enabled="false">
    <mx:HTML id="content" location="https://www.arcgis.com/home/webmap/viewer.html"
    width="100%" height="100%"
    visible="true" 
    verticalScrollPolicy="auto" horizontalScrollPolicy="auto"
    complete="content_completeHandler(event)"
    locationChange="content_locationChangeHandler(event)"/>
</s:Panel>
```

Answer (score 0):

The mx:HTML component is a pretty heavyweight custom implementation of a HTML Rendering Engine. As far as I know it doesn't use a browser, but handles everything itself. I think only parts of HTML, CSS and JavaScript are supported here.

As mx:HTML is only available in Air, I guess you are using this in an Air Application. I would suggest to have a look at the StageWebView class of Air. It's not that comfortable as the mx:HTML component is, but as far as I know this directly utilizes the systems default Browser. So it should be able to display more.